# Any Video Player Not able to Seek Video by Using Temporary Video Source File

Tags: javascript, php, video

I want to avoid my video to download. So i am using this script in order to avoid users to download video and it works!

But I am unable to play this video from any time. This is for Google Chrome only.

Thats why i use following script:

index.php:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();
$vid=uniqid(); 
$_SESSION[$vid]='myVideo.mp4';
echo '<video autoplay="autoplay">'
    .'<source src="video.php?video='.$vid.' type="video/mp4">'
    .'</video>';
```

video.php:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
session_start();
$file='myhiddenvideos/'.$_SESSION[$_GET['video']];
$_SESSION=array();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(),'', time()-42000,$params["path"],$params["domain"],
                                         $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
if(!file_exists($file) or $file==='' or !is_readable($file)){
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found',true);
  exit;
  }
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Now problem with this code is, I can not seek my video or play it from any position of bar at any time!

Live demo: http://thehacktools.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because your video file is being served as a `text/html` file, so the browser doesn't understand what to do with this file. (Well, Firefox understands, Chrome doesn't.)

You must indicate to the browser the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video) of the video via the `Content-Type` [header](http://php.net/header).

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: sorry to say this not worked even in fox and chrome both!..
video is playing .. but can not start from any position..
working if not using my method. :(

using my protecting method of video it's making video live streaming like something...

please help me :)